# How to set image src as a string in vue component?

Tags: image, vue.js, base64

I've created two components to send an image in base-64 encoded format to a server. When the parent component is mounted it's supposed to set the child reference to file.

```
Vue.component('some-form', {
  template: '#some-form',
  data: function() {
    return {
      logoImage: '',
      coverImage: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function(event) {
      var dataForm = {};
      var that = this;
      dataForm['logo-image'] = this.logoImage;
      dataForm['cover-image'] = this.coverImage;

      // AJAX REQUEST HERE with posting data
    },
  },
  mounted: function(){
    var $this = this;

    // AJAX REQUEST HERE with getting data
  }
});

Vue.component('upload-photo', {
  template: '#upload-photo',
  data: function () {
    return {
      image: {
        body: '',
        'content-type': '',
        'content-length': '',
        url: ''
      },
      imageBody: ''
    }
  },
  props: ['logoImage', 'title', 'description'],
  watch: {
    'image': function() {
      this.$emit('input', this.image);
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    this.image = this.logoImage;
  },
  mounted: function () {
    var that = this;
    //AJAX REQUEST HERE to get data
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange: function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length)
        return;
      this.createImage(files[0]);
    },
    createImage: function(file){
      var image = new Image();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var vm = this;
      vm.image = {};

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        vm.image.body = e.target.result;
        vm.imageBody = e.target.result;
      };

      vm.$set(vm.image, 'content-type', file.type);
      vm.$set(vm.image, 'content-length', file.size);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    removeImage: function (e) {
      this.image = '';
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {

  },
  methods: {

  },
  mounted: function() {

  }
});
```

Full example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvzwzO
How can it be implemented?

P.S. I have no idea how to implement it in the same component. I send data as a string with two more property, however get as a string to, however it's link.

P.S.S. need just way to search.

Comment: "_when parent component is mounted it's supposed to set to child reference to file_" it's supposed to set _what_ on the child reference to a file?

Comment: just string with url to file on server

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell exactly what you are asking but it sounds like you want to pass data from the parent component to the child. If you haven't already, read about [Composing components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) and [Dynamic Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props) for passing properties from a parent component to a child component.

One way to do this is to make the `imageBody` a property of the `upload-photo` component instead of part of the data.

```
props: ['logoImage', 'title', 'description', 'imageBody'],
```

Then have the parent supply a value for that property:

```
<upload-photo v-model="logoImage" title="TITLE 1" description="description_1" v-bind:image-body="imageBody">
```

Take a look at [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4xfg-rxnq). When the form is mounted, it sends an AJAX call back to the server to retrieve a URL, then sets the property on that first `upload-photo` child element to the URL sent back from the server in the AJAX response. Note that the `upload-photo` template was changed to show the image if `imageBody` is truthy instead of `image`.